# Dart API: How to send multiple query parameters

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to collect a link of this format  : `fd=1&td=2&test%5Btime%5D=10`.
I have an array

```
Map<String, dynamic> jsonTest = {
      'time': '10',
    };

Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap = {
      'fd': '1',
      'td': '1',
      'test': '$jsonTest'
    };
```

When I try to build a query:

```
var request = Uri.parse("$link/api")
        .resolveUri(Uri(queryParameters: jsonMap));
```

I get this query: `fd=1&td=1&test=%7Btime%3A+10%7D` in `request.query;`

How do I get a query in the form I described at the beginning of my question, thank you all in advance for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the output you want, `jsonMap` will need to have a `Map` entry that looks like:

```dart
'test[time]': '10'
```

Assuming that `jsonTest`'s keys are variable, you will need to iterate over `jsonTest` and add appropriate entries to `jsonMap` yourself.  Dart's [collection-`for`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#collection-operators) construct can do this succinctly:

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> jsonTest = {
  'time': '10',
};

Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap = {
  'fd': '1',
  'td': '1',
  for (var entry in jsonTest.entries) 'test[${entry.key}]': entry.value,
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it really helped, do I understand correctly that I can add other keys to jsonTest?

Comment: Yes, you can add other `'KEY': 'VALUE'` entries to `jsonTest` if you want each of them to result in a query component that looks like `test%5BKEY%5D=VALUE`.